# iptables HTTP ratelimit exclusion with --string Debian 8

Tags: http, debian, iptables

I am trying to limit HTTP requests to maximum 20 requests/second if more than that reject but i want to exclusion requests to (.png,.js,.css) files from this rule, I used the following code

```
iptables -N RATELIMITING
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "/" -j RATELIMITING
iptables -A RATELIMITING -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|woff)$" -j RETURN
iptables -A RATELIMITING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A RATELIMITING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables -A RATELIMITING -j RETURN
```

it does block requests more than 20 requests but it doesn't exclusion (.png,.js,.css) files from rule,if I send 20 requests to those files you also get blocked, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This seems like a poor use of iptables, as HTTP can have more than one request per connect.  I suspect it'd be smarter to do with fail2ban.

Comment: Mainly not the good place. Better ask on serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com (not a programming question)